# Download CER files in IIS and IISExpress, and ISAPI modules

Tags: asp.net, download, certificate, iis-7.5, iis-express

I use **ASP.NET 4.6.1** application.

I use **VS 2012, IISExpress in Windows 8.1** (development environment).

I use **IIS 7.5 and Windows Server 2008 R2** (stagging environment).

I have aspx page for download a *certificate root CA* (.CER file).

I try download the **CER file** (using *IE and Chrome*), clicking in a link in the aspx page:

https://preserver/v2/AccesoAlPortal/public/Certificado/Myrootca.cer

but I get an error; strange characters in IE page:

> 0‚ 0‚õ Xºž,mè\OM‰"æn 0  *†H†÷ 0²1%0# *†H†÷

Save as about link only working in Chrome, not IE.

I add mime type for cer in *IIS site - Mime Types*:

> application/x-x509-ca-cert

but I get the same error.

I try modify my web.config like this:

```
  <location path="AccesoAlPortal">
    <system.web>
      <authorization configSource="Config\system.web.authorization.allow.config"/>
    </system.web>

   <system.webServer>

       <staticContent>

                <!--<mimeMap fileExtension=".cer" mimeType="application/x-x509-ca-cert" />-->
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".cer" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
```

but I get the same error, and other files not viewing right, like gif files.

I older page forum
https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/24467169/IIS-and-download-a-CER.html

I have found this:

> IIS 6.0 has a default ISAPI extenion map that points .cer to asp.dll.
>
> ISAPI filters take presidence over MIME types, thus, it exucutes the
>   .cer through asp.dll, which results in the file being displayed on the
>   browsers screen instead of being prompted to install.
>
> You could rename the .cer to .der, or you can delete the ISAPI
>   Extension.  To Delete, go to the Home directory Tab inside the web
>   site, and under application settings, click on configure, and remove
>   the entry for .cer

Rename the **.cer to .der** is working. But I would like solution without rename file extensions.

In **applicationHost.config** in IISExpress and IIS, I have found this line:

```
 <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Script">

<add name="SecurityCertificate" path="*.cer" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%IIS_BIN%\asp.dll" resourceType="File" />
```

How can I Delete the ISAPI Extension ?
not **Collateral damage** without *ISAPI extension*?

Comment: Comment out that line.

Comment: @LexLi yeah, but which ***Collateral damage***  comment that line ? There are many asp.net applications in company IIS servers.

Comment: ASP.NET has nothing to do with classic ASP. Thus, this change will not affect your web apps. You don't even need to install the ASP component of IIS if you are sure that you won't use it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to download a CER-file (same goes for CRT) you have to change the mime type to "application/x-unknown". When you use "x-x509-ca-cert" you give the browser a clear introduction on how to handle any CER-file, with x-unknown the browser does not know how to treat the file, so by default he is trying to download it.
Also make sure to delete any handler that is configured to redirect CER-files.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the ISAPI module by "Handler Mappings" settings on IIS Manager.

1. Select the target web site or virtual directory on the left pane of the IIS Manager.
2. Double Click the "Handler Mappings" icon in the "IIS" section.
3. Find the setting named "SecurityCertificate".
4. Click the setting by mouse right button, then select "Delete" on the context menu.

Additionally, You should add the MIME type for *.cer file.

1. Select the target web site or virtual directory at the left pane of IIS Manager.
2. Double Click the "MIME Types" icon in the "IIS" section.
3. Add the MIME Type "application/pkix-cert" or "application/x-x509-ca-cert" for the extension ".cer".